# VBA - Read Text of Date as Displayed

Tags: vba, excel

I want to read the text part of the date as it is displayed to compare it else where. The date is formatted in the cell to show as "19 Dec" which is the formatted version for "12/19/2016". How can I be able to read just "Dec" in text? I am writing this to read from an external workbook and I do not have control of that workbook's format. I have part of the code below. The two main lines I am dealing with are "Alpha..." and "Omega..." I have also thought of doing it another way using that commented line of code starting with "ActiveSheet.Range..." Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

```
Sub DataImport()
   Workbooks.Open "\\Issues\Inventory\PA2016.xlsx"
Worksheets("Total Year").Activate
Alpha = Right(Cells(300, 10), 3)
Omega = Right(Cells(600, 10), 3)

'ActiveSheet.Range(Right(Cells(300, 10), 3), Right(Cells(600, 10), 3)).Select

Debug.Print Alpha
Debug.Print Omega
End Sub
```

Comment: If a cell has a date in it, use this to return the three letter month into your variable: `Format(Cells(300, 10), "MMM")`

Comment: Use the Format function Format(<date>, "MMM")

Comment: Oh yes! thank you @tigeravatar  simple fix